# Balanced tree with constant-time successor and predecessor given node pointers?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree

I was asked this question, which I personally find hard:

Create a data structure that can:

Insert elements,
Remove elements,
Search Elements,
In time O(log n)

In addition, 
It should have the following two functions which work in time O(1):

1. next(x):
   given a pointer to the node of value x, return a pointer to the node with the smallest bigger value than x.
2. previous(x)
   given a pointer to the node of value x, return a pointer to the node with the biggest smallest value than x.

Comment: Couldn't that be realised as a regular AVL tree where each node not only points to left and right, but also to next and prev? And update next/prev during add/remove?

Comment: Yes, that's what I also thought of. But how would you update the add/remove function so that every node always points to the next and prev? Keeping them at O(long)?

Even further, I thought to keep the max and min of every subTree for every node. If you calculate the max of your left subTree, and the min of your right subTree, that would clearly return the predecessor and successor.

But again, how could you store them ensuring to stay O(log n). And what would you do about nodes with not both children?

Comment: @saraspagno: Keep in mind that O(50 log n) = O(log n). So you can do a huge amount of bookkeeping, if necessary, without losing the O(log n) guarantee. So the `add` method can find the about-to-be-previous or about-to-be-next element in log *n* time before doing the actual insertion. (And the `remove` method is even easier, because the node itself knows what its neighbors are that will need to be updated, just like with a doubly-linked list.)

Comment: @RogerLindsjö perhaps not a "regular" AVL tree, but it's easy enough to make an AVL tree a [Threaded binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree).

Comment: You can also do this with a modified [Skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list): just make the lowest level of links a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Why does the title mention "AVL", while your question asks for a data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each node contains a pointer to its successor and a pointer to its predecessor, or equivalently - if you maintain both a doublely linked list and a tree, where each node in the tree points to its equivalent node in the list and vice versa - you'll get want you want. Updating the list on insert/delete is O(1) (after locating the closest node in the tree). Searching is performed on the tree. Succesor / predecessor are performed on the list.

Answer (score 2):

@RogerLindsjö's idea from the comments is a good one. Essentially, keep a regular, balanced BST, then thread a doubly-linked list through the nodes keeping them in sorted order. That way, given a pointer to a node in the tree, you can find the largest value smaller than it or the smallest value greater than it simply by following the next or previous pointers in each node.

You can maintain this list through insertions and deletions without changing the overall runtime of an insert or delete. For example, here's how you might do an insertion of an element x:

1. Do a standard BST successor query to find the smallest value larger than x in the tree, and a standard BST predecessor query to find the largest value smaller than x in the tree. Each search takes time O(log n) to complete.
2. Do a regular BST insertion to insert x. Then, set its next and previous pointers to the two elements you found in the previous step, and update those nodes to point to your new node x. This also takes time O(log n).

The total time for the insertion is then **O(log n)**, matching what a balanced tree can provide.

I'll leave it to you to figure out deletion, which can similarly maintain the linked list pointers without changing the overall cost of the operation.

Comment: When trying to locate the place to insert, just keep last nodes seen left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Like most self-balancing trees, a [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) provides Insert, Remove, and Search operations with *O(log n)* time complexity.

In a B+ tree, a leaf node hosts multiple keys in an array, so the concept of "pointer to node with value *x*" does not really exist, but we could define it as the tuple (pointer, index), where the pointer is to the node, and index is the slot in which *x* is stored.

In a B+ tree the nodes at the bottom level contain all the keys, and these nodes are often linked, usually only in forward direction (i.e. to the right), but it is quite possible to also maintain a link in the opposite direction, without increasing the time complexity of the above operations.

With those two remarks in mind, prev-next operations can clearly be executed in *O(1)* time.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are integers you can use [y-fast trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie) that supports all mentioned operations in O(log log m). Also, almost any search tree will allow doing these operations in O(log n) time by just going first up and then down (it will require a lot of concentration to not mess up with the order, though)

Comment: It says that successor and predecessor access takes O(log log M) time, not O(1). While that is extremely efficient, I don't believe that qualifies as O(1).

Comment: Well, yes, but in real life, I seriously doubt it is possible to make everything mentioned in constant-time so this constant will be smaller than log log in the y-fast trie. For 10^9 items in your list log log n will be < 1

Comment: It's M, not n, so the time complexity is dependent on the maximum value, not the number of values.

Comment: It is still a very slowly growing function. The more important problem is that insertions and deletions are only amortized deficient, but their actual time can go up to O(n), so they are not good for real-time applications.

Comment: *"I seriously doubt it is possible to make everything mentioned in constant-time"*  A threaded binary tree gives you O(1) access to next and prev, and O(log n) insertion, deletion, and search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two pointers in the node of the balanced tree, namely `pred` - predecessor and `succ` - successor. While inserting a node into the tree or deleting a node from the tree you just have to do some pointer manipulations, equivalent to those in doubly linked list.
The time complexity will be `O(1)` in each case.

I have provided my implementation for the insertion and deletion in case of *AVL Tree* below. The complete implementation is available [here](https://github.com/abhishekbisht1429/algorithms-and-data-structures/blob/master/data-structures/cpp/avl_tree.cpp).

**Structure of `node`**

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct node {
    T key;
    int freq;
    node<T> *left;
    node<T> *right;
    node<T> *pred;
    node<T> *succ;
    int height;
    node(T key): key(key), freq(1), 
                left(nullptr), 
                right(nullptr), 
                height(1),
                pred(nullptr),
                succ(nullptr) {}
};
```

**`insert` function**

```cpp
node<T> *insert(node<T> *root, T key) {
    if(root == nullptr)
        return new node<T>(key);
    
    if(!comp(key, root->key) && !comp(root->key, key)) {
        ++root->freq;
    } else if(comp(key, root->key)) {
        if(root->left == nullptr) {
            node<T> *new_node = new node<T>(key);
            /* set the pred and succ ptrs*/
            new_node->succ = root;
            new_node->pred = root->pred;
            if(root->pred != nullptr)
                root->pred->succ = new_node;
            root->pred = new_node;

            root->left = new_node;
        } else {
            root->left = insert(root->left, key);
        }
    } else {
        if(root->right == nullptr) {
            node<T> *new_node = new node<T>(key);
            /* set the pred and succ ptrs*/
            new_node->pred = root;
            new_node->succ = root->succ;
            if(root->succ != nullptr)
                root->succ->pred = new_node;
            root->succ = new_node;

            root->right = new_node;
        } else {
            root->right = insert(root->right, key);
        }
    }
    
    root->height = max(height(root->left), height(root->right)) + 1;

    int bf = balance_factor(root);
    node<T> *left = root->left;
    node<T> *right = root->right;
    if(bf > 1 && left != nullptr && comp(key, left->key)) {
        /* 
            node was inserted at left subtree of left child
            fix - right rotate root
        */ 
        root = rotate_right(root);
    } else if(bf > 1 && left != nullptr && comp(left->key, key)) {
        /* 
            node was inserted at right subtree of left child
            fix - left rotate left child
                - right rotate root
        */
        root->left = rotate_left(root->left);
        root = rotate_right(root);
    } else if(bf < -1 && right != nullptr && comp(right->key, key)) {
        /*
            node was inserted at right subtree of right child
            fix - left rotate root
        */
        root = rotate_left(root);
    } else if(bf < -1 && right != nullptr && comp(key, right->key)) {
        /*
            node was inserted at left subtree of right child
            fix - right rotate right child
                - left roatate root
        */
        root->right = rotate_right(root->right);
        root = rotate_left(root);
    }

    return root;
}
```

**`erase` function**

```cpp
node<T> *erase(node<T> *root, T key) {
    if(root == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    
    if(comp(key, root->key)) {
        root->left = erase(root->left, key);
    } else if(comp(root->key, key)) {
        root->right = erase(root->right, key);
    } else {
        if(root->left == nullptr || root->right == nullptr) {
            /* update pred and succ ptrs */
            if(root->succ != nullptr)
                root->succ->pred = root->pred;
            if(root->pred != nullptr)
                root->pred->succ = root->succ;
            
            if(root->right == nullptr) {
                node<T> *temp = root->left;
                delete root;
                root = temp;
            } else  {
                node<T> *temp = root->right;
                delete root;
                root = temp;
            }
        } else {
            // node<T> *succ = minVal(root->right);
            root->key = root->succ->key;
            root->freq = root->succ->freq;
            root->right = erase(root->right, root->succ->key);
        }
    }
        
    if(root != nullptr) {
        root->height = max(height(root->left), height(root->right)) + 1;
        int bf_root = balance_factor(root);
        if(bf_root > 1) {
            /*
                case R 
            */
            int bf_left = balance_factor(root->left);
            if(bf_left >= 0) {
                /* 
                    case R0 and R1
                */
                root = rotate_right(root);
            } else {
                /*
                    case R -1
                */
                root->left = rotate_left(root->left);
                root = rotate_right(root);
            }
        } else if(bf_root < -1) {
            /*
                Case L
            */
            int bf_right = balance_factor(root->right);
            if(bf_right <= 0) {
                /*
                    case L0 and L -1 
                */
                root = rotate_left(root);
            } else {
                /*
                    case L1
                */
                root->right = rotate_right(root->right);
                root = rotate_left(root);
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```